# How to Dselect Usedrange area from spreadsheetgear after using Select Function

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I have a Scenario to print UsedRange area From Spreadsheetgear For that i have used below statement

```
workbookView.ActiveWorksheet.UsedRange.Select();
```

Using above statement i got like below 
[image]

and after that Print works Fine. As soon as this goes for print then i want to Dselect that UsedRange.

Means i want like below

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can move the selected cell back to the first cell in the sheet (or any other cell for that matter) after the print code has run using the `Activate()` method which will deselect the selected cells:

`workbookView.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Activate();`

The API documentation [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.3.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheetWindowInfo~ActiveCell.html) states *To set the active cell, use the IRange.Activate() method.*

I don't think it's possible to have no cell selected so it could be worth storing the selected range before you select the entire contents then after the print re-select the previously selected range with the above code.

Comment: `Activate()` can't be used without calling `GetLock()` first. Using `RangeSelection` property doesn't require locking.